# Suppose X and Y are i.i.d. random variables, where $var(x) < \infty$. Show that $P(|X - Y| > 2) \leq Var(x)/2$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose X and Y are i.i.d. random variables, where $Var(x) < \infty$. Show that $P(|X - Y| > 2) \leq Var(x)/2$.

I assume that I use Markov's Inequality so I get something like 
 
$P(|X - Y| > 2) \leq E[|X-Y|]/2$ 
 
but I am not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Try [Chebyshev's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1=X-EX, Y_1=Y-EY$. Since $EX=EY$ we get $X_1-Y_1=X-Y$ Now use the fact that $P(|X_1-Y_1| >2)\leq \frac {(X_1-Y_1)^{2}} 4$. Since $var(X_1-Y_1)=var(X_1)+var(Y_1)=2var(X)$ we get $P(|X-Y| >2)\leq \frac {var (X)} 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The event $\{|X-Y|>2\}$ is the same as the event $\{(X-Y)^2>4\}$. Try Markov's inequality on this second event.